# How to print address url including #

Tags: php

I want to echo exact url : `http://domain.com/mystuff.html#123456`

but it only print `http://domain.com/mystuff.html` how to include the `#123456` ? so become `http://domain.com/mystuff.html#123456`

my code so far

```
$urladdress =  "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']."?".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```

Comment: browser probably not send `#` (fragment) to server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot. The fragment identifier is handled entirely client side so the browser will not send it to the server.

(The nearest you could come would be to (after the page has loaded) use JavaScript to sent it to the server in another request.)

Comment: thanks, I just want to echo it, how is the javascript code look like ?

Comment: got problem when joining the <a href="'.$urladdress.''.$js.'">text</a> the link is not show #

Comment: ok got the answers from the link above <a href="'.$urladdress.'#'.parse_url("http://foo?bar#fizzbuzz",PHP_URL_FRAGMENT).'">test</a>

Answer (score 0):

you cannot get it using php, you can get it done by javascritp. use this test script to check your result.

```
<script>
alert(document.URL);

    var urlDetail = document.URL;//you can use this variable to print in your web page.
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Found the answer:

```
<a href="'.$urladdress.'#'.parse_url("http://domain.com?page.html#123456",PHP_URL_FRAGMENT).'">text</a>
```